# Explanation of output of this C code

Tags: c, arrays

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    void check(int n, int arr[]);
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    int i;
    check(4, arr);

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);    
    }
    return 0;
}
void check(int n, int arr[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int *p = 0;
    while (i++ < n)
        p = &arr[i];
    *p = 0;
}
```

I need an explanation for the output.

The original question I was asked, and the expected multiple-choice answers, are:

[image: code]

Comment: Don't put images where text could be used !

Comment: Put code *here*, not images of code.

Comment: Did you transcribe the code in order to run it? If so then paste that here. Besides the image-oriented complaints, it's possible you got the `while` statement wrong.

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: What were the answers you had?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: What do you mean by *"correct answer"*?  `check(4,arr)` zeros out `arr[1..4]` not `arr[0..3]`, which is undefined behavior if `arr` is only 4 elements long, which is the case here.

Comment: I've edited back in the expected answers - they were lost in an edit to this question.

Comment: The expected answers still don't indicate what fun() should actually be doing. Currently it zeros the array (inaccurately). Even if that is fixed it still won't result in any of those answers.

Comment: If you change `while (i++ < n)` to `while (++i < n)` it will put `0` in the last element of `arr`.

Comment: But `1, 2, 3, 0` isn't one of the choices. As written, it writes `0` outside the array.

Comment: When I [run this Code](https://ideone.com/wTgbRe),The output is **1,2,3,4,** Which **is** mentioned in choices.

Comment: @Shreevardhan: Yep, that's probably the most common result, and the person who set the question is probably expecting that answer.  But according to the C standards, the program has "undefined behaviour" and it could do anything.  So whoever set the original multiple-choice question made a mistake

Answer (score 2):

Please post your *actual* code, not what you intended to type.  Actually copy-paste your real code.

Because you typed it in wrong.

You either put extra {} in here:

```
while(i++ < n) {
    p = &arr[i];
    *p = 0;
}
```

or you used a comma instead of a semicolon:

```
while(i++ < n)
    p = &arr[i],
*p = 0;
```

and so the assignment to zero ran every time.

Edit to add: Yep, you put extra {} which the original question didn't have.  So in your code, the "*p = 0" executes every time round the while loop, whereas the original question the "*p = 0" only executes once and clobbers some random data that is one past the end of the array.

(By the way, the answer to the original question is actually "it is undefined behaviour; the program doesn't necessarily print anything.  Valid behaviours include printing 1 2 3 4, printing 42 42 42 42, crashing, and formatting your hard drive.")

Comment: please note that the image isn't my code. It's just a question I got. I need an explanation to the output,which is 1,0,0,0 whenever I run

Comment: @BelalFathy What should be the Output ?

Comment: Perfect.    If he used the program as is, then it should give a result of 1, 2, 3, 4.  Cuz, *p would actually reset the value of memory location outside allocated memory for the array, ie., arr[4] = 0 - which would have reset probably the variable i in the main() function, which doesn't have any effect.     Basically it is a bad code and you might not get consistent result in all platforms due to array overflow.

Comment: OMG :D this is correct. So why the while statement is put there ? or is it just a nonsense?

Comment: @Janakiram Depending on the architecture and the compiler, it might clobber a return address and cause a crash, or if you have your compiler's security "detect buffer overrun" options on then it might detect the bug at runtime and abort the program.  A really smart compiler (e.g. clang) may detect the buffer overflow at compile time and optimize the whole program into a single call to abort().

Comment: @user9876, agree. I actually edited my comment that the program might even crash, but I couldn't save. (too many edits may be:))   Thanks that brings clarity.

Comment: @BelalFathy You just said "So why the while statement is put there ? or is it just a nonsense?" ... what should we understand, this is not you code ?..or you have no ideas what are you doing ?

Comment: @BelalFathy What exactly means for you **int *p = 0;** ?

Comment: @Michi: That's perfectly valid syntax to initialize the pointer `p` with a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In `check()`, `i` gets incremented after the comparison, but before the first statement inside.  So the zero (first) element of the array is never set to 0, like the rest are.  `arr`'s 1 stays 1, and 2, 3, & 4 each become 0.

EDIT:
The OP code has changed since the version I discussed.  It's a whole new problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you should know.

First:
you should declare your functions if you declare/define them after main.

Second:
when you declare an Array, the array starts from 0 to n and not from 1 to n.
So, if you declare int arr = {1,2,3,4} then you have arr[0],1,2,3 and not arr[1],2,3,4.

Third:
you should avoid code like:

```
while (i++ < n) {
    p = &arr[i];
    *p = 0;
}
```

And use:

```
while (i < n) {
    p = &arr[i];
    *p = 0;
    i++;
}
```

Fourth:
What exactly did you expected from this:

> int *p = 0;

Anyway, you just try to access a memory location that not belong to you.

Comment: The fourth point: `int *p = 0;` initializes the pointer `p` with a null pointer.  It's perfectly kosher.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what choices you're talking about, however the cause of your output is here:

```
int i=0;
int *p=0
while(i++<n)
{
    p=&arr[i];
    *p=0;
}
```

Variable 'i' starts at 0 but you increment it before entering the loop so the first index of the array is ignored. You then set a pointer to array index 'i' and then immediately dereference the pointer and set the value to 0;

Because of this any array you pass will always retain its first value whilst every other value will be zero.

if you want to include the first index of the array you'd be much better off doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    // stuff
}
```

With this, 'i' is not incremented until after the code between the braces has been executed.